# jQuery Easing Undefined function

Tags: jquery, shopify, easing, uncaught-exception

I recently migrated an update of a store onto a shopify server. After doing so a few jquery issues occured even though it was working on the developement server. They fail to work with the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function - Jquery Easing`
```

Im struggling to debug this as it worked on my other server. How would I go about debuging this?

The issue can be seen here by hovering over the image and seeing the warning in the console

```
http://thebrotique.co.uk/products/original-beard-oils
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dig into the console error it you'll be able to start debugging.

It is occurring in your `jQuery.easing` code: `jquery.easing.1.3.js:46`

```
swing: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    //alert(jQuery.easing.default);
    return jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def](x, t, b, c, d);
}
//jQuery.easing.def is undefined
```

It's expecting some default value. If you define `jQuery.easing.def` to a valid value like `"easeOutQuad"` it will start working.

Comment: Thanks @peterdotjs . How would I setup the default value? Its confusing because it worked on the other site.

Comment: Actual just got it working. Thanks. I am confused why it would be different compared to the other server when the 'theme' is the same

Comment: @Allreadyhome it actually looks like something else is going on, it doesn't look like jQuery.easing code is fully loaded. If it was `jQuery.easing.def` would already be defined.  If you take the easing code: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gdsmith/jquery.easing/master/jquery.easing.js and load it in the console everything works as is.